# Is there a way to update my coin information?

Tags: assets, accounts, stellar.toml

A guy on Fiverr built me the ESA token, and I wanted to add my website and some details to the metadata or profile. Is there a way to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create `stellar.toml` file and host it on your domain like `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/stellar.toml`. Check this [guide](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/issuing-assets/publishing-asset-info/) which explains the process in detail.

Do not forget to set `home_domain` for the issuing account and configure correct CORS headers for your `stellar.toml`, otherwise it may be inaccessible from web clients.

Comment: I did that already. It's at esatoken.xyz. It took all day because I'm coding illiterate at the moment. (:P) but how do I communicate that I've done it with Stellar and get verified? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with your setup: https://stellar.sui.li/toml-check/esatoken.xyz

Comment: @DoYouRightProfessionalSEO There is no any special verification process. Once you fix the error, all clients will be able to fetch the data automatically. The metadata will appear here: https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/ESA-GBKRGDJLZPP2YMI6MNZ52QM3I5AFEJ5VEBSYKGVJPZXHZ67RWQSVGLUQ

Answer (score 0):

If the issuing account is locked then you cannot update the information that is in the digital asset. If you used Fiverr to create the asset, then you need to remove those assets from any wallet they created with it, so that they do not try an come back in and remove funds from the wallet. Which has happened many times with Fiverr and a few bad apples that create assets for their clients. Also, unless you asked them not to lock the issuing account then they locked it and being how you had to have them make the tokens then you would not have known to not lock it, even if you change the info on the toml file it will remain showing a warning to investors and does not look good, it's better to recreate them.